# c++ terminology 2 part question reguarding "declaring" vs "initializing" variables

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, terminology

Just trying to clarify my thoughts here.
Here's my current understanding.

**part 1**:
Declaration vs initialization...

My understanding is that you can declare a variable without giving it a value and doing so is called declaring an **uninitialized** variable?
eg.

```cpp
int var;
```

Declares int var without initializing it.  Correct?

Whereas declaring a variable with a value we would say we're initializing this variable with the value {v}...

```cpp
int var = 0;
```

- Yes?  No?  Something totally different?

**part 2**:
Also if you're not going to give it a value why declare it at all?  I see this all the time but I don't know if there's a reason to do it this way as opposed to assigning a value when you create it.  Is it idiomatic or aesthetic preference or is there a reason?  If there's a reason, should you ALWAYS do it this way?  What's the time and the place and limitations?
eg.

I often see this...

```cpp
int var;
var = 0;
```

Why not just do this?...

```cpp
int var = 0;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What source are you using to learn C++? What does it say about this topic?

Comment: I'm drawing from a number of sources none of them give an explicit opinion they just assume one approach or the other and it often seems inconsistent.  I'm wondering if the declaration before assignment approach is meant to demonstrate that it's possible or that it's preferred, if there's a reason to prefer one or the other it's never been made clear to me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel On a related note I'm about 30 hours into studying, this isn't my first programming language but I've mostly worked in higher level interpreted languages, I sorta got into rust a number of years ago but I really wanna dive deep with c++.  If you know of good resources I'm open to suggestions. :)

Comment: You can start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242

Comment: @cigien Excellant resource, thank you! :D